# How can I keep result of pyimport more than a second?

Tags: echo-area, message

I am using https://github.com/Wilfred/pyimport to insert missing imports using `M-x pyimport-insert-missing`.

*Example:* `Path()` where its import is missing. When I bring cursor on top of `Path` and apply `pyimport-insert-missing` it shows `from pathlib import Path` in the echo area (which also added on top of the buffer), and after a second its definition shown (I believe due to `lsp-python`). Its pretty short time for me the check whether the correct import module is added or not.

=> Would it be possible to keep result of `pyimport-insert-missing` more than few seconds?

Comment: Try adding `(sit-for 3)` after the call to `message` in `pyimport-insert-missing` (line 229 in the curent code). If that works, adjust the duration to taste. It seems you have dueling extensions, fighting for territorial rights over the echo area.

Comment: @NickD I have realize that flycheck also fights for the territorial rights in order to give message as `Undefined variable 'func' `.  As I understand I have to run `(flycheck-buffer)` right before `(sit-for 10)` in order to prevent it. I have tried following: `(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-o") (lambda () (interactive) (pyimport-insert-missing) (flycheck-buffer) (sit-for 10)))` but it gives error :-(

Comment: @NickD I have also realize that I had `(setq flycheck-check-syntax-automatically '(save mode-enable))` definition on my config file, which leads to flycheck to applied late which also cause its output to show up in the race